# Integrability and Continuity on Interval

Tags: continuity, monotone-functions, bounded-variation, partitions-for-integration

If $g$ is continuous on $[a, b]$ and if $f$ is integrable on $g([a, b])$, then $f \circ g$ is integrable on $[a, b]$.

One of the famous theorems reveals that if $f$ is continuous on some compact interval, then it will be integrable there. However, it seems the above problem does not utilize such useful properties. Are there any further suggestions for it?

Comment: Interesting question to ponder about

Comment: This should help: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/20045/about-the-riemann-integrability-of-composite-functions